# Should you put a comma after a question mark in a title in quote marks?

Tags: punctuation, commas

The convention would be to drop a comma after a question mark in normal speech:

> “Do you want to come to the movies with us?” Mary asked.

Rather than:

> “Do you want to come to the movies with us?”, Mary asked.

But what about when the question mark plays very little to no grammatical function in the scentence, such as in a title.

E.g.

> He completed a dissertation titled 'To what extent was Mao responsible for the 1959-61 Great Famine?' for which he studied many secondary and primary sources.

Or

> He completed a dissertation titled 'To what extent was Mao responsible for the 1959-61 Great Famine?', for which he studied many secondary and primary sources.

This question is separate from [What punctuation to use when quotation ends in a question mark?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/381401/what-punctuation-to-use-when-quotation-ends-in-a-question-mark).

Because A) it's not about whether the question mark should go inside the quote marks. That is unambiguously the case because it is part of the title.

And B) it's about a scenario where the question mark has no effect on the meaning of the sentence.

> The sentence is:  He completed a dissertation titled [title], for
>   which he studied many secondary and primary sources.

Whether or not the [title] unit contains a question marks seems less relevant to the meaning of the sentence compared with, for example:

> “Do you want to come to the movies with us?” Mary asked.

In the latter structure relaying the question is the primary purpose of the sentence, whereas in the former the question is entirely incidental.

Comment: @Laurel This is not a duplicate of that question. Please see my edits.

Comment: I reread everything and the duplicate does answer your question. Especially the Grammar Girl quote in the accepted answer that references Chicago style.